# Operator acting on a product of functions

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, eigenfunctions

Let $f \in \mathcal{H}$ be a function $f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ in a Hilbert Space $\mathcal{H}$.
Now suppose that for some linear operator $T$ that acts on $\mathcal{H}$ and for some $f \in \mathcal{H}$:
$$T(f) = \lambda f$$
For some $\lambda \in \mathbb{C}$. That is, $f$ is an eigenfunction of $T$ with eigenvalue $\lambda$. Now suppose that $f$ can be written as $gh$, where $g,h \in \mathcal{H}$ and
$$T(g) = \alpha g$$
And
$$T(h) = \beta h$$
Then how do we define the operation $T(hg)$ in a way we can write it in terms of $\alpha, \beta$?

My professor said that, in this case, $\lambda = \alpha + \beta$, but this doesn’t look clear to me. I have tought that maybe the operation is
$$T(gh) = T(g)h + gT(h)$$
Which would give the correct result, but I can’t see this working for some operators (ex: second order differential operator, $D_x^2$ or taking the antiderivative).

How do we define $T(gh)$ and how to relate $\lambda$ to $\alpha$ and $\beta$?

Comment: If we only know $T$ is linear,  we cannot deduce anything specific for the connection between $\lambda$ and $\alpha,\beta$. Nevertheless, if $T$ satisfies the Leinitz rule, we get a clear connection $\lambda=\alpha+\beta$ - as you noted. If, on the other hand, $T$ preserves multiplication ($T(gh)=T(g)T(h)$) then we obviously get $\lambda=\alpha\beta$.

Comment: It is interesting to point that out. It seem fairly clear to me now that one must specify other properties of the operator in order to properly understand the relations between eigenvalues. I personally think that your comment could be turned into an answer.